# How to efficiently store calculations from different combinations of variables and factor levels in a data frame?

Tags: r

I'm hoping to get some help on writing some more efficient code for a particular task that I'm doing. My example may be a little complicated, so I'll do my best to explain it. Essentially, I'm wanting to perform some precision (`p`), recall (`r`) and F1 (`f`) calculations based on the levels of a factor variable (`ex$v`) and for each combination of targets and predictions. Here is my example data.

```
# Example data.
set.seed(100)
ex <- data.frame(
  v = c(rep("slo", 50), rep("mod", 50), rep("fas", 50)),
  sr = c(rep(c(100, 800), 75)),
  A = rbinom(150, 1, 0.8),
  B = rbinom(150, 1, 0.8),
  C = rbinom(150, 1, 0.8),
  D = rbinom(150, 1, 0.8),
  E = rbinom(150, 1, 0.8)
)

ex$v <- as.factor(ex$v)
```

So far, I have attempted to write a function that quickly manipulates `ex` to create a custom confusion matrix. In this particular example, `A` is my target and `B` is my prediction for `ex$v[slo]` only. Initially, I wrote this function to save repeating the `dplyr` lines of code for subsequent combinations of targets and predictions.

```
# Function to create custom confusion matrix.
f <- function(dat, sp, hz, target, pred){
  
  dat %>%
    filter(v == sp & sr == hz) %>%
    select(target, pred) %>%
    table() %>%
    as_data_frame()
  
}

# Test function.
test <- f(dat = ex, sp = "slo", hz = 100, target = "A", pred = "B")
```

In this isolated example, I then calculate precision (`p`), recall (`r`) and F1 (`f`) from `test` using these three lines of code.

```
# Precision/recall/F1 calculations.
p <- test$n[4] / (test$n[4] + test$n[2])
r <- test$n[4] / (test$n[4] + test$n[3])
f <- 2 * (p * r) / (p + r)
```

This gives me the scores for A and B, but I want to repeat this process for six more combinations of targets and predictions and for each level of `ex$v` and store these in a `tibble`/`data.frame`. However, I only want `A` and `B` to be my targets. This is where I'm stuck. I'm wondering whether there is a way to formulate the code into a loop or in some other way that makes this process a bit more efficient, rather than continually repeating the lines of code shown here and joining each separate output manually. I'd like the `tibble` to look something like the example below, where `.x`, `.y` and `.z` would represent each level of `ex$v`, which are different speeds.

```
Comp    p.x   r.x   f.x   p.y   r.y   f.y   p.z   r.z   f.z     
B - A   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
C - A   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
D - A   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
D - A   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
C - B   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
D - B   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
E - B   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I hope that all makes sense. Any help with this will be fantastic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option which gives the output in a long format.

```
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(dat, sp, hz, target, pred){
  test <- dat %>%
    filter(v == sp & sr == hz) %>%
    select(target, pred) %>%
    table() %>%
    as.data.frame()
  
    p <- test$Freq[4] / (test$Freq[4] + test$Freq[2])
    r <- test$Freq[4] / (test$Freq[4] + test$Freq[3])
    f <- 2 * (p * r) / (p + r)
    tibble(sp, hz, target, pred, p, r, f)
}

cols <- names(ex)[-(1:2)]


crossing(as.data.frame(t(combn(cols, 2))), v = unique(ex$v), sr = unique(ex$sr)) %>%
  pmap_df(~f(dat = ex, sp = ..3, hz = ..4, target = ..1, pred = ..2))

#    sp       hz target pred   p     r     f
#   <fct> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 fas     100 A      B     0.895 0.739 0.810
# 2 fas     800 A      B     0.8   0.842 0.821
# 3 mod     100 A      B     0.789 0.75  0.769
# 4 mod     800 A      B     0.870 0.952 0.909
# 5 slo     100 A      B     0.826 0.95  0.884
# 6 slo     800 A      B     0.706 0.632 0.667
# 7 fas     100 A      C     0.737 0.7   0.718
# 8 fas     800 A      C     0.65  0.765 0.703
# 9 mod     100 A      C     0.737 0.7   0.718
#10 mod     800 A      C     0.957 0.917 0.936
# … with 50 more rows
```

`combn` creates all combinations of names and using `crossing` we also create every combination of unique `v` and `sr` values which are passed to the `f` function.

Comment: Thanks, @Ronak. I think this will be very useful for me. Really appreciate it.